# when apply something in position it will apply also on other position in custom ListView

Tags: java, android

a weird problem happened with me, when i apply something (like drop down, visibility, background) on a linear at position, it will also apply it on other position.

for understand me this a picture of my problem :

[image]

and this is my Adapter, whats wrong ?

```
public class Listview1Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data;

        public Listview1Adapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arr) {
            data = arr;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int index) {
            return data.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int index) {
            return index;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int _position, View _v, ViewGroup _container) {
            LayoutInflater _inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = _v;
            if (v == null) {
                v = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.online_block_list, null);
            }

            
            final ImageView drop_more = v.findViewById(R.id.drop_more);
            final LinearLayout linearMore = v.findViewById(R.id.linearMore);
            final LinearLayout linearDro = v.findViewById(R.id.linearDro);
            



            linearDro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (linearMore.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            
                        final android.transition.ChangeBounds transition = new android.transition.ChangeBounds(); transition.setDuration(200L);
                        android.transition.TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(listview1, transition);
                        linearMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drop_more, View.ROTATION, 0f, 180f).setDuration(300).start();

                    } else {
                        final android.transition.ChangeBounds transition = new android.transition.ChangeBounds(); transition.setDuration(200L);
                        android.transition.TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(listview1, transition);
                        linearMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drop_more, View.ROTATION, 180f, 0f).setDuration(300).start();

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` reuse views returned by `Listview1Adapter.getView()` method. You get a situation when view for some item change itself - the state of View instance(object) was changed (expanded). Then ListView pass as an argument of `Listview1Adapter.getView()` method a same View's instance for other item - this view already expanded.

You should save state of view for each item of ListView (in your case for `data` ArrayList) and restore it for each item in `getView()` method. It might look like:

```
public class Listview1Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    final ArrayList<ItemState> data;

    public Listview1Adapter(ArrayList<ItemState> arr) {
        data = arr;
    }

    private static class ItemState {
        final HashMap<String, Object> data;
        boolean isExpanded;

        public ItemState(final HashMap<String, Object> data, final boolean isExpanded) {
            this.data = data;
            this.isExpanded = isExpanded;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int index) {
        return data.get(index).data;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int _position, View _v, ViewGroup _container) {
        LayoutInflater _inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = _v;
        if (v == null) {
            v = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.online_block_list, null);
        }


        final ImageView drop_more = v.findViewById(R.id.drop_more);
        final LinearLayout linearMore = v.findViewById(R.id.linearMore);
        final LinearLayout linearDro = v.findViewById(R.id.linearDro);


        if (data.get(_position).isExpanded) { // check current view state for item
            linearMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // restore view state for current item
        } else {
            linearMore.setVisibility(View.GONE); // restore view state for current item
        }


        linearDro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (linearMore.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

                    final android.transition.ChangeBounds transition = new android.transition.ChangeBounds();
                    transition.setDuration(200L);
                    android.transition.TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(listview1, transition);
                    linearMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    data.get(_position).isExpanded = true;  // save view state for item

                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drop_more, View.ROTATION, 0f, 180f).setDuration(300).start();

                } else {
                    final android.transition.ChangeBounds transition = new android.transition.ChangeBounds();
                    transition.setDuration(200L);
                    android.transition.TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(listview1, transition);
                    linearMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    data.get(_position).isExpanded = false;  // save view state for item

                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drop_more, View.ROTATION, 180f, 0f).setDuration(300).start();

                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

You have many options to convert your items to ItemState objects, I show a few bellow:

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listMapTest = new ArrayList<>(); // input data

// 1th
final ArrayList<ItemState> viewListMapTest_1 = listMapTest.stream().map(item -> new ItemState(item, false)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        
// 2th:
final ArrayList<ItemState> viewListMapTest_2 = new ArrayList<ItemState>() {{
      for (HashMap<String, Object> item : listMapTest) add(new ItemState(item, false));
        }};
        
// 3th:
final ArrayList<ItemState> viewListMapTest_3 = new ArrayList<>(listMapTest.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < viewListMapTest_3.size(); i++) {
        viewListMapTest_3.set(i, new ItemState(listMapTest.get(i), false));
    }
```

Comment: brother thanks so much to answer and help, but i just get a small problem that is :              when i set the adapter to my listview ....    listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(listMapTest));
                      
The constructor MainActivity.Listview1Adapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>) is undefined

Comment: im using array list HashMap<String, Object> any suggestion?

Comment: @Hasni List view display each item of `ArrayList`. The item's type is a `HashMap<String,Object>` i.e. this can looks like [HashMap<String,Object>, HashMap<String,Object>, ...., HashMap<String,Object>]. In my sample i wrap each item to `ItemState` class i.e. you should pass  `ArrayList<ItemState>` as parameter of Listview1Adapter. It's easy to convert your array to array with new type - please, see sample in my edited answer.

Comment: i got it, Thank you so much Brother for your Help